# What are the differences between these two boundary conditions?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, heat-equation

i'm struggling to understand the difference between inhomogeneous and homogeneous, for example if i was to solve the following Pde

$$100\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}, 0<x<1,t>0$$
with conditions $u(0,t)=0,t>0$,$u(1,t)=0,t>0$ $u(x,0)=\sin(2\pi x)-\sin(5\pi x),0\le x\le 1$ 
I know these conditions are homogeneous. However if i was to consider the next PDE $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=2\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$$ with boundary conditions $u(0,t)=5,t>0$, $u(\pi,t)=10,t>0$, $u(x,0)=6,0<x<\pi$

I don't understand why these conditions are inhomeogenous. I was wondering if anyone could explain why. I have already Solved these Pde's just going along with the fact that the conditions are inhomeogenous for the second one.

Comment: Do you mean the boundary conditions or the PDE itself?

Comment: Often, the term homogeneous is used to describe a condition which is equal to $0$. In the first PDE, you have $$u(0,t) = \color{blue} 0, \quad u(1,t) = \color{blue} 0$$ and are thus considered homogeneous, while in the second PDE your conditions are $$u(0,t) = \color{red} 5, \quad u(\pi, t) = \color{red} {10}$$ and hence considered inhomogeneous. Note that terms homogeneous and inhomogeneous have very specific meanings in other contexts.

Comment: @CheeHan I mean just the conditions

Comment: @Mattos thank you for your explanation